# What is the function of "Volume up + Volume down" Combo?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, buttons

1. Phone L535DS
2. OS : W10M(10.0.15047.0-Fast Ring)

As we all know <kbd>**VolUp**</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> combo is designated for taking screenshot and <kbd>**VolDown**</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> is designated for launching Feedback Hub. But when I press <kbd>**VolUp**</kbd> and <kbd>**VolDown**</kbd> buttons simultaneously for three times, a strange thing happens.

1. My phone vibrates three times.
2. Then screen goes black for a very short interval of time.
3. Then return to its previous state.

I'm unable to understand what my phone is doing and for what purpose this combo is used. I can't figure out any change or can't see any app launched.**So my question is that what exactly this combo does and for what purpose it is used?**

Comment: The only explanation I've found is [this forum thread at Windows Central](http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10/378834-what-do-you-think-pressing-volume-up-volume-down-3-times-really-does.html) where people suggest it just does a display reset. Supposedly works on Windows 10 PCs as well, though it didn't on my SP3 when I tried.

Comment: @Indrek I also searched and read many things like that but I was unable to find exact answer. Moreover it doesnot resets display for me but in fact nothing I can observe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a tickle test (see http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10-mobile/409900-press-volume-up-volume-down-3-times.html ).
If you keep pressing <kbd>**VolDown**</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> you will do a soft reset.

Answer (score 1):

the function performed after the volume up, volume down combo is simply a hardware diagnostic test called the "Tickle Test", Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?